# Changing notify-send with notifyosd

Tags: debian, gnome3, notifications

Because I'd like to use notify-osd (Ubuntu-Style notification) instead the default notification  I'm wondering how to stop the second one for enabling the first one.
In particular, (trying googling) how system notification works, it seems to me "like looking for a needle in a haystack" because there are a bunch of possibilities. I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/837455/how-to-make-notify-send-work-on-etc-init-d-a-script/837491#837491)  that notify-send communicates with D-Bus, but nothing is well exposed to give me an idea well sorted out (I've found a lot of Ubuntu material but it looks quite different). So it should be appreciated some links that shows me an idea how the entire process works as well as the steps to solve my initial question.

OS : Debian Jessie

DE : Gnome 3.14.1